# Cambiar ruta para guardar un archivo creado con PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Uso la librería PHPExcel para crear un archivo excel con datos de una BD, el problema es que me guarda el excel generado en la ruta del servidor donde está el archivo php que lo generó, el siguiente código es un fragmento de lo que utilizo, me gustaría poder elegir la ruta de descarga para ese archivo.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;

$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que poner la ruta en el método save:

Ruta relativa:

```
$objWriter->save('../../files/archivo.xls');
```

Ruta absoluta

```
$objWriter->save('/var/www/files/archivo.xls');
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Te se abrirá una ventana que selecciones donde guardar tu excel.
Recuerda que debes abrir una ventana desde el JS de tu vista:

```
window.open("https://localhost/exportarExcelReportes");
```

Ejemplo:

```
public function expotarExcelReportes() {
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$sheet3 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet3->setTitle("NombreHojaCalculo");
$sheet3->setCellValue('A1', 'Programa');
$sheet3->setCellValue('B1', 'Cod. Materia');
$sheet3->setCellValue('C1', 'Materia');

$data = ModalDataQuery::getFuncionSQLMostrarData(); //Traer Data

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $sheet3->setCellValue('A' . ($key + 2), $value['programa']);
    $sheet3->setCellValue('B' . ($key + 2), $value['codmateria']);
    $sheet3->setCellValue('C' . ($key + 2), $value['materia']);
}
$nombreDelDocumento = "Reporte-en-Excel.xls";
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $nombreDelDocumento . '"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$writer->save('php://output');}
```